# Python min() function grabbing highest number

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using a tkinter GUI to get a bunch of different entries from the user, and I want to grab the smallest number out of a group. But when I use the min function to find the smallest number, it gives me the highest. It happens every time I use the following code (variable names change):

```
GCFz = int(min([z2, z3]))
```

And when I reversed it (to use max() instead), it gave me what I wanted (the smallest number).

z2 and z3 are entrybox.get() variables from the GUI.

Example wanted input/output:

input: z2 = 5, z3 = 11
output: GCFz == 5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Text boxes give strings. Convert to numbers first.

```
>>> min(['11', '5'])
'11'
>>> min([11, 5])
5
```

Comment: Well crap, I feel stupid. Thanks, I would have wasted a lot of time trying random crap xP

Answer (score 3):

If `z2` and `z3` are strings, comparing them will be alphabetical, meaning `"11"` is smaller than `"5"`.

You can use `min ((int(z2),int(z3))`